# Scrolling 2D Tiles

Tags: performance, array, actionscript-3

**update:**
So, this is weird, I just reinstalled Adobe Animate, and now, when I do ctrl+enter (test movie), it pulls up an AIR window, and plays my app, and it works smooth as butter! (now I'm just not able to install a published package because I screwed up something with my certificate...)

I have just posted 1 out of 4 conditionals that comprise this function.  They are all nearly similar, but I don't know a way to do this without writing it 4 times.

This code runs when I pan down in a map of 2D tiles (AS3 code):

```
        } else if (pan == "down"){
            // tracks the position of the level view/camera
            onScreenTopRow++;   

            //////////////////
            // remove tile from Top
            //////////////////
            // arrGround is 2D array that stores the tiles, split by tile tipe.
            // I did this to avoid having to create tiles while scrolling
            // all the needed tiles get created at initialization, and reused as needed.
            // I know I could make that more efficient by only creating new tiles
            // if that array is empty, but this works for now
            var removedArray:Array = onScreenArray.shift();
            // removes top row of tiles from view, then iterate through that to
            // push them back into the arrGround storage array
            for (var i:int = removedArray.length; i > 0; i--){
                // t = Tile removed from top of column
                var t:Tile = removedArray[removedArray.length-1];
                // tileNum = Tile Type
                var tileNum:int = tileType(t);
                // add tile from onScreenArray to arrGround
                arrGround[tileNum].push(t);

                // add Tile from top of column
                // I just do this to position it back at top z-order so I can
                // visually track what is happening while I debug this.
                addChild(t);
                t.x = tileNum * offScreenDeckSpacingX * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckX;
                t.y = arrGround[tileNum].length * offScreenDeckSpacingY * SCALE_UP + offScreenDeckY;
                removedArray.pop();
            }       

            //add new Bottom Row
            // add a new empty array inside the main array for tiles to make the bottom row
            onScreenArray.push([]);

            // for each col
            // then iterate through the new array, grab the right tile from
            // arrGround, and push it in
            for (var i:int = 0; i < lenCols; i++){

            /////////////
            // add tile to Bottom
            /////////////

                // botRow = bottom tile row
                var botRow:int = onScreenRows-1 + onScreenTopRow;
                // tType = bottom tile Type
                var tType:int = complexArray[botRow][i+onScreenLeftCol];
                // t = Tile to take from arrGround
                var t:Tile = arrGround[tType][arrGround[tType].length - 1];
                // tile on bottom of pertinent column
                var bottomTile:Tile = onScreenArray[onScreenArray.length-2][i];

                // add tile from arrGround to onScreeArray
                onScreenArray[onScreenArray.length-1].push(t);
                // remove tile from arrGround to onScreenArray
                arrGround[tType].pop();

                // place tile on screen
                t.y = bottomTile.y + tileWidth;
                t.x = bottomTile.x;
            }
```

It works fine in Flash player, but when I compile it for AIR, it takes a HUGE pause when creating the new bottom row (like about down to 4 fps!).  Oddly, it does fine when scrolling up, left, or right or just when using Flash Player.  The only differences are that when scrolling left and right, I'm not adding or removing arrays from the 2D array, but rather just pushing and popping array elements (on the right and left side) and when I scroll up, I'm shifting in a new top row and popping off the bottom row (array).

Comment: I can't say with 100% certainty, but you can probably avoid the four separate `if` statements by using a dictionary. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html

Comment: I only see `addChild(t)` in this code to put a tile on screen. When/how are they removed again?

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow They are all added to the stage at the initialization. After that they aren't added or removed exactly. They just get pushed/popped from an array of tiles that is in the viewer and that gets looped through for panning, and another array that just holds unused tiles.

Comment: Then what is the `addChild()` in your code for? Your comment in the code says `// place tile on screen`, but you just said that they are already on screen!?

Comment: I'm just using the addChild method to move that tile to the top of the z-order. It's been helpful in catching my errors when I have managed my array methods wrong. I'm seeing that the second one, at the bottom, is not helpful (neither are necessary), so I've removed it. I'll remove or comment the other one out once I no longer need to visually track things.

Comment: I reinstalled Adobe Animate and it seems to be working very smoothly now.  So weird.